# Axon 3 not found handler

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, axon

I'm beginner with Java. I would configure my handler only for working and processing command. At this moment I receive `Exception` `No handler was subscribed to command [com.capgemini.books.CreateBook]`.

My code looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class ControllerConfig {
    @Bean
    public CommandBus commandBus() {
        return new SimpleCommandBus();
    }
}

public class CreateBookHandler {
    public CreateBookHandler() { }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(CreateBook command) {
       Book newBook = new Book(1001L, "anonymous", command.bookTitle());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hope I can help you with this :-)

Taking you're running your application through Spring Boot and that you're using the `axon-spring-boot-starter` dependency to wire everything automatically, then I know what you're missing. 
The `CreateBookHandler` is not a Spring Bean, hence the auto wiring set up of Axon doesn't notice it as a bean and thus cannot find the `@CommandHandler` annotated function on it.

Additionally though, I'd typically put my command handling functions directly on the aggregate rather then in a separate component within my setup. Reason for that is because commands are most of the times in the context of a single aggregate, so why not let the aggregate itself handle it?

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: You are 100% right. I forgot about mark handler as a bean. Maybe not forgot, I'm just beginner with this technology stack. Thank you for patience and accurate answer.

Comment: No problem, I'm happy to have been of help with this! :-)